# hide specific html in list view

Tags: jquery, listview, knockout.js

I have a dynamically created list view that shows a list of locations and how far away these locations are.  For one of these locations (WFH), I dont want the line `<span data-bind="text: distanceBetweenPoints"></span><span>&nbsp; mi.</span>` to appear at all.  So how can I change this so that if locationName == 'WFH' nothing appears from the next `span`.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <ul id="nearbyLocationsListView" data-bind="template: {name: 'locationsListTemplate', foreach: nearbyLocations}" data-role="listview" data-filter="false"></ul>         
    <script id="locationsListTemplate" type="text/html">
        <li>
            <div>       
                <span data-bind="text: locationName"></span>
                <span data-bind="text: distanceBetweenPoints"></span><span>&nbsp; mi.</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </script>
</div>
```

Here is where the list is being created:

```
function GetClosestLocationByCoordinates() {
    var url = 'http://localhost/GetClosestLocationByCoordinates;

    var jqxhr =
    $.getJSON(url,
    function (data) { 
        $.each(data.GetClosestLocationByCoordinatesResult, function (key, val) {
            var distanceBetweenPoints = distance();
            nearbyLocationsModel.addNearByLocations(val.LocationId, val.LocationName, val.NumberCheckedIn, distanceBetweenPoints);
        });
        ko.applyBindings(nearbyLocationsModel, document.getElementById("nearbyLocationsListView"));
    })
}
```

Comment: Either Michael's answer or mine will work. The difference is that Michael's will set the div he added to display:none, while mine actually takes the spans out of the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <ul id="nearbyLocationsListView" data-bind="template: {name: 'locationsListTemplate', foreach: nearbyLocations}" data-role="listview" data-filter="false"></ul>         
    <script id="locationsListTemplate" type="text/html">
        <li>
            <div>       
                <span data-bind="text: locationName"></span>
                <div data-bind="visible: locationName() !== 'WFH'">
                    <span data-bind="text: distanceBetweenPoints"></span><span>&nbsp; mi.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </script>
</div>
```

You can also use the `If` binding instead of `visible`. 
Note that `If` removes the element from the page while `visible` simply hides it.

More details can be found on KO site: [If binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html), [Visible binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html)

Comment: This seems simple enough and I looked through the documentation, but it doesnt seem to be working

Comment: @Mike: try adding '()' to locationName, i've updated my answer.
Since you are comparing to a string, you need the observable value and not the observable itself.

Answer (score 0):

To do so without your DOM structure being changed:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <ul id="nearbyLocationsListView" data-bind="template: {name: 'locationsListTemplate', foreach: nearbyLocations}" data-role="listview" data-filter="false"></ul>         
    <script id="locationsListTemplate" type="text/html">
        <li>
            <div>       
                <span data-bind="text: locationName"></span>
                <!-- ko if: locationName !== 'WFH' -->
                    <span data-bind="text: distanceBetweenPoints"></span><span>&nbsp; mi.</span>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </li>
    </script>
</div>
```